# JNI: best way to pass global variable to-and-fro with smallest overhead?

Tags: java, java-native-interface

So I have a global integer array declared within my Java code which is allocated just once that I'd like to be able to cache a raw pointer to within the initialization routine of my JNI code. Is this even possible (or does the VM reserve the right to hand me a copy of the array)? If not, could I instead allocate the memory (say via NewIntArray) from the JNI side, then pass that to the Java code just once to be cached?

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrays, just like all other objects, can be moved around in the heap memory by the garbage collector. If you want a block of data that won't be moved (and you can cache a pointer into) you need to use an off-heap `ByteBuffer`.

In JNI you can create one using the [`NewDirectByteBuffer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#NewDirectByteBuffer) function: reserve memory outside of the Java heap using `malloc` and call this function to create a `ByteBuffer` object that wraps the memory.

If you want to create the buffer from the Java side, you have [`ByteBuffer.allocateDirect`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#allocateDirect%28int%29). The JNI function `GetDirectBufferAddress` then returns the pointer to the raw memory buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [Returning jint array from c to java through jni](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11686200/returning-jint-array-from-c-to-java-through-jni). Question seems pretty simimlar to yours.

Basically if you pass an int array to a method in java, you can access it in jni as `jintArray` type.

I am not aware of copies being made, basically in jni you access the same object as in java code.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question as it does not involve a *pointer* to the storage of a variable in a specific memory location which will endure after the jni call returns.

Comment: @Chris i got it, pointer to a java int array won't endure as the location of the object in memory can be changed by the gc, which is not true for direct buffers. Thanks for pointing it out.